# Adding an announcement to site or to "ask a question" form

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think that we need a content box which informs users (*especially* new users) about minimum requirements for posting a question (e.g. version of Magento if applicable). What would we all like to see in this content area? Curious to know too if StackExchange platform allows for this as well.

Comment: Great idea. Do you know what way is used to submit this request to StackExchange?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt posting like this on meta, with the `[feature-request]` tag, is exactly the right way to submit requests to us at SE. I've just been a bit behind on responding, and I apologize for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "content box" exactly? Some kind of pop-up help on the question asking page? An interstitial page for new users who have never asked before? Custom text on [the "on-topic" page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the help center?

Comment: Something like: Please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store before asking questions. Please add what you coded, what you expect, what happens instead and what you already tried. And a link to http://whathaveyoutried.com is a good idea as well :-)

Answer (score 4):

#### Suggestions for a popup on the "Ask question" page:

- Always specify your **Magento version**
- If you have questions about **custom code**, please include the relevant code, and explain current and desired behavior
- If you have questions about an **error**, read [Debugging Fundamentals](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) first, and gather information about the error
- Questions about problems with **commercial extensions** do not belong here. Please contact the extension vendor support instead.

The list should not be longer than 5 items, otherwise nobody will read it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what we should have, beside all helping links:

https://twitter.com/sprintly/status/549982608340549632

[image]